# How to load only the events created by a specific user into DHTMLX-Scheduler?

Tags: database, yii2, dhtmlx-scheduler

I would like to have only events displayed from the currently logged in user.

How can I achieve this?
I have already configured the event to have a user field.

I am using the `JSONSchedulerconnector` to populate the `DHTMLX-Scheduler`.

```
$connector = new JSONSchedulerConnector(null, "PHPYii");
$connector->set_options("subsubprojects", $subsublist);
$connector->set_options("subprojects", $sublist);
$connector->set_options("projects", $list);
$connector->configure(new Booking(),"id", "start, end, activity, user, project, subproject, subsubproject, status, comment");
$connector->render();
```

UPDATE:
I have tried the filter method, as documented here:
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/connector__php__filtration.html#filtermethod

I have inserted before render:

```
$connector->filter("user", "2");
```

But it does not work...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not obvious why filter("user", "2") doesn't work for you on the server-side without a demo.

I suggest you use filtering method on the client-side (that described on this page https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/filtering.html), it will be easier. You just need to check the logged user and render events according to the "user" value in data.

Comment: Thanks Polina, that is what I did (as a workaround). Obviously it is not nice to have all data and just "hide" the unnecessary ones, but this is how it seems to be working right now. I hope that I can solve that somehow on the server-side though...